Likelihood and marginal compatibility
Given a joint $T(o, s) = T(o|s)T(s)$, and a marginal $T(o)$.
I am trying to publish a paper claiming (among other things) that some likelihood $T(o|s)$ and marginal $T(o)$ are not compatible. In other words, for some pairs $T(o|s)$ and $T(o)$, there is no $T(s)$ satisfying:
$$T(o) = \sum_s T(o|s)T(s).$$
For example, if:
$$T(o|s) = Cat(o | s; A) = \begin{bmatrix}
0.6 & 0.4\\\\
0.4 & 0.6
\end{bmatrix}$$
and:
$$T(o) = Cat(o; C_o) = \begin{bmatrix}
0.8\\\\
0.2
\end{bmatrix}.$$
We let $T(s) = Cat(s; C_s)$, such that $T(o) = \sum_s T(o|s)T(s)$ can be written as a following matrix product: $C_o = AC_s$, which is a linear system of equation. To solve it, we first find the inverse of A:
$$A^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}
3 & -2\\\\
-2 & 3
\end{bmatrix},$$
then, we get the result as follows:
$$C_o = AC_s \Leftrightarrow A^{-1} C_o = C_s \Leftrightarrow \begin{bmatrix}
3 & -2\\\\
-2 & 3
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}
0.8\\\\
0.2
\end{bmatrix} = C_s = \begin{bmatrix}
2\\\\
-1
\end{bmatrix}.$$
Since $C_s$ are the parameters of a probability distribution, its values should be between zero and one, and sum up to one. Since this is not the case, and the inverse of a matrix is unique (if it exists), then my conclusion is that there does not exist of distribution $T(s)$ satisfying $T(o) = \sum_s T(o|s)T(s)$ for the above likelihood and marginal.
However, a review is claiming that I "[...] cannot use linear algebra (i.e., the inverse of A) to invert probabilistic mappings. There is an interesting literature on how to invert probabilistic morphisms in category theory (sometimes framed in terms of Bayesian lenses) that you may want to look at some point."
Question: Is my reasoning incorrect? If so, why is my reasoning incorrect? What error did I do?
